# Error when uploading larger videos using Youtube API v3 resumable upload (on AWS EC2)

Tags: php, video, amazon-ec2, youtube

On my AWS EC2 instance, I'm able to use the Youtube API (PHP) to upload videos. My video files are stored on AWS S3, so when uploading to Youtube, my PHP script will download the file to EC2, and then upload using the Youtube API to Youtube.

This seems to work OK for videos that less than 100MB, but not files that are larger than that.

Anyone has any idea what the problem could be? Below is a snippet of the library codes used to perform the upload:

```
$snippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
if (array_key_exists('title', $data))
{
    $snippet->setTitle($data['title']);
}
if (array_key_exists('description', $data))
{
    $snippet->setDescription($data['description']);
}
if (array_key_exists('tags', $data))
{
    $snippet->setTags($data['tags']);
}
if (array_key_exists('category_id', $data))
{
    $snippet->setCategoryId($data['category_id']);
}


/* ------------------------------------
#. Set the Privacy Status
------------------------------------ */
$status = new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = $privacyStatus;

/* ------------------------------------
#. Set the Snippet & Status
------------------------------------ */
$video = new \Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);

/* ------------------------------------
#. Set the Chunk Size
------------------------------------ */
$chunkSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

/* ------------------------------------
#. Set the defer to true
------------------------------------ */
$this->client->setDefer(true);

/* ------------------------------------
#. Build the request
------------------------------------ */
$insert = $this->youtube->videos->insert('status,snippet', $video);

/* ------------------------------------
#. Upload
------------------------------------ */
$media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $this->client,
    $insert,
    'video/*',
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSize
);

/* ------------------------------------
#. Set the Filesize
------------------------------------ */
$media->setFileSize(filesize($path));

/* ------------------------------------
#. Read the file and upload in chunks
------------------------------------ */
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($path, "rb");

while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSize);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
}

fclose($handle);

/* ------------------------------------
#. Set the defer to false again
------------------------------------ */
$this->client->setDefer(true);
```

I turned on CURLOPT_VERBOSE to see the output during uploading and below is an excerpt of it:

```
* Connection #0 to host www.googleapis.com left intact
* Hostname www.googleapis.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 74.125.130.95...
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (74.125.130.95) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: *.googleapis.com
* Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> PUT /upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Ur4P0Fpf3GsMWAoc6dUIeXmQXuAfdhuIP1jIbQJPyVQm0aqZ0NGuljcT-U0c5hW2wrE-AepZMghHOzpvkUZb-I9zBruAw HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
content-range: bytes 19922944-20971519/388638417
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 1048576

* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
< X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Ur4P0Fpf3GsMWAoc6dUIeXmQXuAfdhuIP1jIbQJPyVQm0aqZ0NGuljcT-U0c5hW2wrE-AepZMghHOzpvkUZb-I9zBruAw
< Range: bytes=0-20971519
< X-Range-MD5: 5f5ce9766e0b823edb947b9a93ee3fd6
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 07 Apr 2016 09:01:06 GMT
< Server: UploadServer
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25"
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.googleapis.com left intact
* Hostname www.googleapis.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 74.125.130.95...
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (74.125.130.95) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: *.googleapis.com
* Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> PUT /upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Ur4P0Fpf3GsMWAoc6dUIeXmQXuAfdhuIP1jIbQJPyVQm0aqZ0NGuljcT-U0c5hW2wrE-AepZMghHOzpvkUZb-I9zBruAw HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
content-range: bytes 20971520-22020095/388638417
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 1048576

* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Operation timed out after 100000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0


  [Google_IO_Exception]                                                
  Operation timed out after 100000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

It seems after uploading for a while, the upload would suddenly stop. I thought it could be due to the memory limit of the server, so I upgraded the EC2 instance type, which resolved the issue for this video file, but when uploading another larger file, the same thing happens again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here, in case it may help some else:

The trick was to increase the chunk size so that larger chunks are sent to YouTube at one time. Solution came from here:

http://www.softwarehorizont.com/2016/03/youtube-api-v3-connection-timeout-on.html

Comment: The link is not working as of today.